# Create multiple dictionaries in one line without reference to others?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create multiple dictionaries in one line, I tried like following.

```
a,b,c = dict(), dict(), dict()
```

Is there any pythonic way to achieve this? I tried with

```
a = b = c = dict()
```

But in this, if I change `a` it also reflects with other dicts

```
a['k'] = 'val'

a
{'k': 'val'}

b
{'k': 'val'}

c
{'k': 'val'}
```

Comment: Your `a,b,c = dict(), dict(), dict()` is working

Comment: yes, its working perfectly, but I want to know is there any better option than this ?

Comment: No. It is perfectly fine.

Comment: You could do `a, b, c = [dict() for _ in range(3)]`. But I think this is actually *less* readable.

Comment: This `a = b = c = dict()` means one dict with three names. Just for completeness.

Comment: More Pythonic would be to ditch your multiple variables and work instead with a list, `my_dicts = [dict() for _ in range(3)]`. The `3` could then take any value.

Comment: The "pythonic way" is actually to initiate the variables in multiple rows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just posting some thoughts here:

Pep 8 is a style guide for python code: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. However nothing about declaring variables there.

Although these work:

```
a,b,c = dict(), dict(), dict()
a, b, c = [dict() for _ in range(3)]
```

I think this is the most readable:

```
a = dict()
b = dict()
c = dict()
```

Reason:

You can always expect that variables are defined on separate rows. What about if  you were to assign 20 items, would it be: a,b,c,d,e.... ??

Anyhow, another way of doing it would be to nest them inside one dictionary, and here too only one variable is declared:

```
dicts = {letter:dict() for letter in list("abc")} # {'a': {}, 'b': {}, 'c': {}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is fine. use

```
a,b,c = dict(), dict(), dict()
```

The explanation for the second method :

> Python variables are references to objects, but the actual data is
>   contained in the objects.

`a = b = c = dict()` is not creating three dict. In python, variables don't store the value. Variables point to the object and objects store the value, so here `a,b,c` variable pointing same object which contains one `dict()`. you can check

```
print(id(a),id(b),id(c))
4321042248 4321042248 4321042248
```

That's why when you change in one, it changes the other too because they are holding the same dict value.